# Cant access property of req.user

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm writing in Node using passport.js to authenticate.

```
console.log(req.user);
```

returns

```
{ group: 'CuManager',
  password: 'password',
  username: 'administrator',
  cu_id: 2,
  _id: 569fd3f4328ef124be533caf }
```

but

```
console.log(req.user.cu_id);
```

returns

```
undefined
```

I was thinking that cu_id property maybe is not available due to serialization/deserialization, but it's there. I just can't access it.
How can I do that?
I need it for

```
find({cu_id : req.user.cu_id})
```

BTW I can't help thinking passport.js is little overcomplicated (maybe we just don't get along). What else can I use to authenticate users in Node (I use express)?

Comment: try `console.log(req.user['cu_id']);`

Comment: @peteb, already tried it - still undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `req.user` is a Mongoose document, you should probably add `cu_id` to the proper schema.

Otherwise you can use something like `req.user.toObject().cu_id` to access the property, or make sure that somehow the result of `doc.toObject()` is assigned to `req.user`.

As for a Passport-replacement: this depends on how exactly you want to authenticate your users. If you're `POST`'ing a login form to an Express route, you can perform the password validation and session setup yourself.

Comment: that's it, I forgot to update schema with cu_id. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try parsing it in JSON.

```
JSON.parse(req.user)['cu_id']
```